# "command not found: pub" after Flutter installation

Tags: flutter, path

Flutter and its commands work fine, but pub doesn't work:

```
% pub global activate fvm
zsh: command not found: pub
```

I've tried adding paths to the .bash_profile file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Admin/Developer/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Admin/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Admin/.pub-cache/bin"
```

I'm using OS Catalina on Apple Silicon M1 and Flutter 2.0.3

Why is pub command not found?

Comment: Keep only the first path, and run `source ~/.bash_profile` after saving the file then `which flutter dart` what do you get?

Comment: Make sure you closed that window and reopen the bash to create a new session

Comment: And is your username actually literally `username`? Might want to check that out.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad after these commands I get /Users/Admin/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter and
/Users/Admin/Developer/flutter/bin/dart. I've replaced my actual username for privacy, sorry for confusion

Comment: @Arash I closed the window and even tried restarting my computer for no avail

Comment: if you are getting these results, you should be good to go

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad but pub command is still not found

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running:

`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm trying to install FVM with "pub global activate fvm"

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the FVM docs, it looks like you need to install dart by itself, separate to a flutter install.

To do that follow the instructions here: https://dart.dev/get-dart

Once you have done that you should be able to follow the rest of the FVM docs.

For more on this see this github issue: https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm/issues/183

Comment: I did and it asked to update my path and after that fvm command is still not found. Also, FVM documentation recommends installing only with pub command

Comment: After looking at the FVM docs it looks like you need to use dart as it is when you install it stand alone. Not bundled with flutter as you have it. I have updated my answer, after verifying on my machine.

Comment: after installing with dart fvm commands don't work: "fvm help" returns "command not found: fvm"

Comment: Can you verify that fvm is installed?
If so can you also confirm that it is in your path?